# ORA-01017: invalid username/password при попытке соединиться с 9i oracle database при помощи ODP.NET, Managed Driver

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

Я пытаюсь соединиться с 9i oracle database при помощи The ODP.NET, Managed Driver и каждый раз вижу ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied.

С версиями 10g или выше подключение происходит без проблем.

Также я могу нормально установить связь с 9i при помощи поставщика данных .Net Framework для Oracle или .Net Framework для OLE DB (MSDAORA).

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ODP.NET, Managed Driver используется если .NetFramework >= 4.0 и database >= 10g.

Comment: Да, ты прав. Нашел официальную документацию в подтверждение твоих слов, вот: [ODAC 12c Release 2 (12.1.0.1.2) Installation Instructions, Setup, and Notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/install121012-2088160.html)